# Selenium IDE how to verify the text of the tooltip in a table

Tags: tooltip, selenium-ide

Hi I have a scenario to test in selenium IDE, is the text of a 'tooltip' to a specific element in a table correct? This is not the only tooltip in the table. I found an answer of sorts in http://seleniumatmindfire.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/verify-tool-tip-text-in-selenium.html#comment-form 
but I'm not able to get the text from the title="add note" of the tooltip. Attached is a screen print showing the 'tooltip' pops up as 'add note' which isn't correct (an issue has been raised). I'm pretty new to this type of testing and have found answers when I'm stuck but I am struggling to get the correct store command and target - the closest I got is

```
<tr>
    <td>storeElementPresent</td>
    <td>.//*[@id='opportunities-table']/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]/a@title</td>
    <td>tooltip</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${tooltip}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

echo prints as 'false' - I need it to print the tooltip title to compare and verify.

a copy of the code:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: transparent;">
<div id="portal_service_dialog" class="jqmWindow jqmID1">
<div id="csi_dialog" class="jqmWindowCSI jqmID2">
<script type="text/javascript">         jQuery(function() {             // initialising a Widget object starts .live listening for dialog_link clicks             var $Widget = new Widgets({  });         }) ;         </script>
<div id="subMenuSection">
<div class="pageContent">
<div id="csi_opportunities" class="row-fluid">
<div>
<div style="height: 25px;">
<div id="edit-custom-table-view-container" class="hide"/>
<div id="search_results" style="">
<div id="opportunities-table_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper">
<div class="dataTables_table_paging_div">
<table id="opportunities-table" class="table table-condensed dataTable" style="">
<thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="cs_details_value">
<td class=""/>
<td>
<td/>
<td class=""/>
<td class=" sorting_1">
<a class="external_link" target="_blank" title="add note"![enter image description here][1] href="/cgi-bin/index.cgi/CustomerService/Opportunities/view/e62f3cb8-791a-4ae4-1c5e-5388b0dd72a1" style="background-color: transparent;">3</a>
</td>
<td>
<td class="text align right">100</td>
<td class="text align right">0</td>
<td>
<td>New</td>
<td class="text align right">50%</td>
<td/>
<td>
<td>
<td>
</tr>
<tr class="cs_details_value">
<tr class="cs_details_value">
<tr class="cs_details_value">
<tr class="cs_details_value">
<tr class="cs_details_value">
<tr class="cs_details_value">
</tbody>
</table>
<div class="bottom_pagination">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance as I'm sure theres simple way to do this, please let me know if there is any other info required.
Jeff

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try `storeAttribute` instead of `storeElementPresent` as the [origin references](http://seleniumatmindfire.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/verify-tool-tip-text-in-selenium.html)

Answer (score 0):

I need to thank @Hai Lu... and after some more thought I tried CSS locator adding @title and using storeAttribute echo now produces the 'title' of the tooltip:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeAttribute</td>
    <td>css=td..sorting_1 &gt; a.external_link@title</td>
    <td>tooltip</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${tooltip}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

[info] Executing: |echo | ${tooltip} | 
[info] echo: add note
I can now compare and verify.
Thanks again